# Infinity Loop when updating a state inside useEffect function with dependency array

Tags: reactjs, loops, state, onchange, use-effect

Scenario:

I've a custom MultiSelect component that's working fine, but, I'm trying to do a onChange function to it that uses a useEffect function with his options array as dependency.

Obviously, all the state management of the options selected/unselected are inside of MultiSelect component, and I guess this is the issue.

I'm trying to set a state when another state changes, but I'm got a infinity loop. I've tryied to make another states to validate if the previous state is equals to current state, but not working. I'm searching for a solution has a long time, but all solutions that I tryied not work. :(

Here's my code, someone can help me, please?

MultiSelect.tsx

```js
const Multiselect: React.FunctionComponent<IMultiSelectProps>({
    data = [],
    touchableRippleStyle, 
    entityName = "Item",
    entityGenre = "M", 
    onChange,
    defaultAllChecked = false}) => {
    
    const _data = convertToItemData(data, defaultAllChecked);
    const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(_data as IItemData[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("MultiSelect options changed");  
        onChange(options);
    }, [options]);
    
    ...
    
    ...
})
```

Form.tsx

```js
function reducer(state: IFilterState, action: FilterActions) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'clients':
            return {
                ...state,
                clients: action.payload
            }
        default: return { ...state }
    }
}

const Form: React.FunctionComponent<FormProps> = ({navigation}) => {
    const [clientsEntity, setClientsEntity] = useState([] as Client[]);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, filterInitialState);
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    return 
    (<MultiSelect 
      data={convertToMultiSelectOptions(clientsEntity)}
      defaultAllChecked 
      entityName="Clients"
      entityGenre="M"
      touchableRippleStyle={{margin: 15}}
      onChange={clients => { 
          console.log("onChange clients: ", clients);
          dispatch({type: 'clients', payload: clients});
      }}
    />)
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I delete the initial dot from the question the "Hello, " gets removed too 

Comment: Yeah, because of this I have put the dot at the first word, maybe a bug?

Comment: Maybe your `onChange` is updating the value that you pass down to the `data` prop of `MultiSelect`?

Comment: Not, my onChange is updating another state inside the Form.tsx. I don't know why it's happening.